# Loading different sizes of images in list view android

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

Have been searching a lot for my requirement, didnt find any luck. 
I have a listview where I am using imageLoader to load the image in the view but the images are of different height. If I give height to wrap_content it doesnot display anything. and If I give minheight to it then it stucks on the same height.

Any Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

Comment: It looks like you are defining the images as the `ImageView`'s background because you should be able to use `wrap_content`.

Comment: do you use volley, do not you?

Comment: No I dont use volley. Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @Pratik recommended, [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) is a perfect solution.